# numpy detection of borders in 2-d array

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, classification

I have matrix (below), which represents classes (e.x. 0,1,2). I am plottling it with plotly (python) using heatmap, and I can't find any function which will give me the coordinates of classes' borders.

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The black lines below are borders, could you give some tips to calculate it in python efficient way? Checking every element in array and its neighbour works very slow.

[image]

upd. I also tried to look in plotly contour plot, but the shape of lines has interpolation so it looks no as in the exmaple above...

Comment: Did the answer help sergey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`skimage.measure`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html) to find the components in the array. Since `0` is considered to be "background", you'll have to change the label to another one, the maximum value +1 for instance. This will give you tuples of slices with the coordinates.

Labeling is necessary if blocks with the same label are not necessarily "attached", or in the same component. Otherwise you can directly use `regionprops` to find the slices.

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

a[a==0]=a.max()+1
l = label(a)
for s in regionprops(l):
    print(s.slice)
(slice(0, 4, None), slice(0, 10, None))
(slice(2, 10, None), slice(0, 10, None))
(slice(4, 10, None), slice(3, 10, None))
```

Input data:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```